# How can I make viewport to view center of the page?

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage which is not really responsive but I am trying to make it at least friendlier on phones. See: http://maguss.org

My current viewport is: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=500, initial-scale=1">`

It is looking fairly ok, but the entire view is on the left side of the page. I would like to force it to center.

I was browsing around here but couldn't find any answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should let the width be the device width as follows

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Then use media-queries to change the behaviour of your page.

Comment: This is not recommended for sites that are not designed responsively.

Comment: Agree with Aziz, I need a different solution ;/

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your styles add this:

```
html, 
body {
   width:100%; 
   height: 100%;
   position: relative; 
}
```

Next find this ruleset:

```
.main{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Change it to:

```
.main{
    height:100vh;
    width:100vw;
    position:relative; // or absolute; you need to test it.
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: It broke down the entire page. Nvm most likely there is no solution as the current page is not made in the best way, code-wise.

Comment: Despite it's structural flaws, it looks very nice on the surface. Perhaps try design for mobile first and then design for desktop afterwards, I hear it's what the popular kids do nowadays.

Comment: Heard the same too. Thanks! :)